# Show Heatmap of aggregated measure by state(lat longs)

Tags: tableau-api

Currently, I have data with latitude, longitude, and value. What I want to show is a heatmat by US, state containing the average of value for those data points in that state. What I've done so far is set my columns to long, rows to latitude, and color to AVERAGE(value). Unfortunately, this gives a bunch of points on my map, not aggregated by state lines. I want to ignore points out of the US and aggegate this by state. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create a calc field with Level of Detail fixed on State, like so.

> {fixed [State]: avg([Sales])}

Place this field on the Color shelf. Here's a sample workbook. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hompp84i4zfc26g/AAAjqQJ-01Jo35pmJ08v4ZKEa?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Creating a filled map works out of the box.

If you have a field with state names or abbreviations, make sure you set its Geographic role to State/Province by right clicking the field in the data pane. You should see a globe icon next to it in the data pane. If your field is named State, then that will be the default.

Double click the State field. Tableau should then, as a shortcut, put your State field on the detail shelf and the generated latitude and longitude fields on the row and columns shelves. Place Avg(Sales) on the color shelf.

At this point Tableau should display a filled map. If not, you can change the mark type from Automatic to filled map to insist.

Note, Tableau has built-in geocoding information about state boundaries, which is what the generated latitude and generated longitude fields represent. So you don't need latitude and longitude fields in your data set just to color a state map.